# phpize error in Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.6 (/opt/local/bin/perl: bad interpreter: No such file or directory)

Tags: php, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I'm trying to use phpize and it always throws this error:

```
/opt/local/bin/autoconf: /opt/local/bin/autom4te: /opt/local/bin/perl: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/opt/local/bin/autoconf: line 492: /opt/local/bin/autom4te: Unknown error: 0
```

The line 492 of /opt/local/bin/autoconf is:

```
exec "$AUTOM4TE" "$@"
```

I was trying to install mcrypt in the built-in php, since I couldn't I started to using MAMP, but now I need to install memcache and I have to use phpize again and of course it doesn't work.

It doesn't matter which phpize I use, the one in /usr/bin/phpize, the one that comes with MAMP and it always throws the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like perl isn't installed. Ironic, ain't it? Requiring perl to be installed to build PHP.

Comment: I think more importantly is why is it looking in /opt/local/bin when those files are in /usr/bin?

Comment: I bet it would work if you do it by the book. That is, from scratch, component by component, without the MAMP crap.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by making the following symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin /opt/local/bin
```